Sign In With Google Button is not Being Displayed on Angular
I have implemented sign in with google button by following the guide on https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button
I first load the library in head tag of index.html like
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>

and I have place the login code like in my login component like
                    <div>
                        <div id="g_id_onload"
                            data-client_id="CLIENT_ID"
                            data-context="use"
                            data-ux_mode="popup"
                            data-callback="handleGoogleCredentialResponse"
                            data-auto_prompt="false">
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="g_id_signin"
                            data-type="standard"
                            data-shape="rectangular"
                            data-theme="outline"
                            data-text="signin_with"
                            data-size="small"
                            data-logo_alignment="left">
                        </div>
                    </div>

Now this code did work perfectly fine and displayed the google button but yesterday i uploaded the build (i worked on other stuff unrelated to the sign in) on the server and the google sign in button stopped displaying on the login page and there is no error on the console either.
